# Food identification in fajitas - yellow sauce

Tags: sauce, food-identification

I'm looking for the name of a yellow/ochre colored sauce, used in fajitas among other things. I've been to a tiny Mexican restaurant a couple of times and in there the guy made his fajitas with such a sauce.

Now, I know that description isn't worth much, but I was hoping somebody could help me nonetheless. I can't really ask him, since I don't know his contact information, plus his shop isn't exactly close either. The shop is pretty small and it's in West Europe, so it may or may not be 'authentic' Mexican cuisine.

Comment: In general, "[fajitas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fajita)" don't have any sort of sauce on them at all... so I'm not really sure what to say. Can you explain what the sauce tasted like. There are probably dozens of sauces that are yellow... taste will tell us much more than color.

Comment: Welcome. If you perform a search for 'fajita sauce' you should get a ton of results for both recipes and ready-to-use products that you can purchase.

Comment: Yeah, I feared as much. It's pretty hard to tell the taste, cause he made a big mix of ingredients in the fajitas, which isn't atypical of course. Not spicy, maybe a little sweet. Not particular sour either I think.

Comment: @Cindy I don't get the same results you do... perhaps it's a regional thing. The only results I get when I search for "fajita sauce" is marinades and spice mixes and some jarred products, none of which are "yellow".

Comment: Could it be the Orange-yellow of saffron? I really don't know. Most fajitas I've eaten have no sauce or a little bit of a tomato-chili residue from the pan. Probably cooked marinade. Then tomato salsas, guacamole, and/or sour cream.

Comment: This could be anything from Hollandaise to Chili Aioli or even cheese sauce. My bet is on chili aioli.

Comment: This got auto-bumped, so I went ahead and closed it; I think the comments and answer demonstrate pretty clearly that this description unfortunately isn't quite enough to go on.

Answer (score 1):

This does not sound like a traditional fajita sauce. The yellow color is likely to be from achiote (annatto), which is widely used in Mexico. It has a mild peppery taste, but is used more for color than for flavor.